# MVC start up old project on debug after copying

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, copy, rename, copy-paste

I just copied a MVC project, made some changes to the new instance, but when I try to run it, for some reason it tries to run my old project instead of the new one.

I have renamed everything (did a windows search for file contents, not sure if it finds everything), cleared bin, cleaned the project, rebuilt.

When that still didn't work, I deleted the local copy of the other project, which resulted in this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUdg3.png

I have tried to find a solution, to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Do clean , rebuild, remove the temporary asp.net files and check

Comment: I removed /obj and /bin, that didn't work. Did you have other folders in mind? Unfortunately, I'm fairly new to asp mvc :)

Comment: Try to delete the contents of temp asp.net files